# Modal popup in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, simplemodal

Please, check my [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lFOPOwz9MnhKQ4bljRLm?p=catalogue).

I am planning to get a modal popup when the user login is incorrect. That means in  `app.js` at line `54` else part I'm planning to trigger the content in `login.html` from line `40` to `54` as modal popup. but I am unable to do that.

Comment: Please post relevant code in the question itself. There is a  reason you weren't allowed a link without providing any code. We shouldn't have to go offsite to understand your issue. Questions should be self contained and use links only to support what is in the question itself

Comment: Also be more specific about what *"unable to do that"* means